# Prevent contact from unsubscribing from a mailing list?

Tags: civimail

I have a case where we have optional mailing lists for our members, but also a mandatory list that members must not be able to unsubscribe from (a smart group that looks for active members -- our master list of members -- which we use to contact them about urgent issues). A condition of membership is that they need to remain on this list.

But, when I send a mailing with the {unsubscribe} placeholder, members see all the lists they are on, including the master list, which they can then unsubscribe from.

Is there a way to prevent a mailing list from being displayed on the Unsubscribe page?

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a way to prevent a mailing list from being displayed on the Unsubscribe page?

If the Mailing Group is not set to Public then it should not show I believe.

Comment: There are also more custom solutions eg using Webform in Drupal to decide what Groups people can join/leave

Answer (score 2):

{action.unsubscribeUrl} should only unsubscribe them from that single mailing list and not display all your groups.

You do have to include an unsubscribe URL - civicrm forces you to include (body_html:action.optOutUrl or action.unsubscribeUrl) or you can't send the email. There is a setting to sidestep the requirement for OptOut per *petednz - fusion* but use at your own risk.

Comment: There is a setting to sidestep the requirement for OptOut